# if I add anything inside componentWillUnmount nothing happening

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I am trying to learn react myself.
- I am trying to set session inside my componentWillUnmount.
- but if I add anything inside componentWillUnmount nothing happening.
- i debugged by adding console and debugger still nothing happening.
- can you guys tell how to make my componentWillUnmount to work
- so that in future I will fix it myself.
- providing my relevant code snippet and sandbox below.
- all my code is in RecipeReviewCard.js

https://codesandbox.io/s/1vqkz1own7

```
 componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount---->");
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("componentwillUnmount---->");
    debugger;
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(
      "favoriteValues",
      JSON.stringify(this.props.benchMarks)
    );
  }
```

Comment: I see the console log 'componentwillUnmount----->' when I change tabs - seems to be working fine

Comment: can you post the code that's related into the question?

Comment: componentWillUnmount is called before the component is destroyed, it is not for making session.

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky hey is there any way can we make it work when we refresh the page for componentwillUnmount

Comment: @RudolfOlah hey that is what I posted in the question am I missing something :(

Comment: @PeterAmbruzs can you let me know which is the best method in lifecycle hooks for sessions

Comment: @all can you help me with negative mark...I tried and posted :(

Comment: seems like you want `componentWillMount` - fires before the component is shown

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky if that's the answer, please add it. no ssr, I re-read the question + code, nevermind my previous comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggests, 'componentWillUnmount' will fire when the component is about to be taken out of the DOM (eg. when you switch tabs for example) and in your example the `console.log` indeed does fire. Use 'componentWillMount' to run the function when the component is loaded into the DOM

Comment: @Velmir: can you help me this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53903369/using-react-redux-loading-bar-package-in-that-i-am-trying-to-show-loading-bar-co?noredirect=1#comment94655426_53903369